# Finding the maximum possible sum/product combination of integers

Tags: algorithm

Given an input of a list of N integers always starting with 1, for example: 1, 4, 2, 3, 5. And some target integer T.

Processing the list in order, the algorithm decides whether to add or multiply the number by the current score to achieve the maximum possible output < T.

For example: [input] 1, 4, 2, 3, 5 T=40

```
1 + 4 = 5
5 * 2 = 10
10 * 3 = 30
30 + 5 = 35 which is < 40, so valid.
```

But

```
1 * 4 = 4
4 * 2 = 8
8 * 3 = 24
24 * 5 = 120 which is > 40, so invalid.
```

I'm having trouble conceptualizing this in an algorithm -- I'm just looking for advice on how to think about it or at most pseudo-code. How would I go about coding this?

My first instinct was to think about the +/* as 1/0, and then test permutations like 0000 (where length == N-1, I think), then 0001, then 0011, then 0111, then 1111, then 1000, etc. etc.

But I don't know how to put that into pseudo-code given a general N integers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A "brute force" approach with pruning would do. An efficient implementation can be made using dynamic programming

Comment: So it seems you don't know how to print numbers from 0 to 2^N-1, in binary.

Comment: Are the integers positive ? Cannot solve the question without this information.

Comment: The title misleading. It should be like " Finding closest possible sequential sum/product combination of positive integers"

Comment: @Rerito There is no need to apply dynamic programming here. It is a binary tree. Usual bracnh and bound with  >= T will be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use recursive to implement the permutations. Python code below:

```
MINIMUM = -2147483648
def solve(input, T, index, temp):
    # if negative value exists in input, remove below two lines
    if temp >= T:
        return MINIMUM
    if index == len(input):
        return temp

    ans0 = solve(input, T, index + 1, temp + input[index])
    ans1 = solve(input, T, index + 1, temp * input[index])
    return max(ans0, ans1)

print(solve([1, 4, 2, 3, 5], 40, 1, 1))
```

But this method requires O(2^n) time complexity.